# SharePoint Server 2010: Create drill-down reports/charts

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, reports, chart

Can we create drill down reports or charts using SharePoint 2010 out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Well that's kinda tough job with OOB controls, SharePoint 2010 has default chart webpart with limited set of options but one thing to note - the webpart has hell lot of problem when your need is beyond 'just basic chart', for numerous reason Microsoft discontinued the chart control feature in SharePoint 2013 and AFAIK they dont have any plan to include the control in future, so I would suggest you to use [Collabion Charts for SharePoint](http://www.collabion.com/), that's the best tool for your purpose

Comment: is Collabion free?

Comment: For evaluation it's free, you can download the product and test it